# Stringstream is not recognized in while loop

Tags: c++, file, getline, stringstream, file-io

Set2 while loop does not populate for some reason. Set1 works just fine.

```
std::stringstream ss;
std::string line;
std::getline(infile, line);
ss.str(line);
int input;

// Populate set1
while(ss >> input)
{
    set1.insert(input);
    std::cout << "Populate set1 with " << input << "\t pos is " << set1.getUsed() << std::endl;
}

// Populate set2
std::getline(infile, line);
ss.str(line);

std::cout << "\n2nd getline verification: " << line << std::endl;

while (ss >> input)
{
    set2.insert(input);
    std::cout << "Populate set2 with " << input << "\t pos is " << set2.getUsed() << std::endl;
}
```

It only populates set1 and not set2. Thank you for your help.

Edit: It reads getline now, thank you. But it doesn't inport the values in "line" to the ss stringstream, so for some reason the second loop for set2 doesn't get recognized.

Comment: What *does* your program do? Where is `infile` defined? have you opened the file?

Comment: Yes it is defined. set1 imports just fine. set2 does not.

Comment: If you've solved your previous problem, please update the code to reflect that as it's highly confusing to keep the old code and refer to a corrected and working update without any evidence of it. Also, what is `set1` and `set2`? I know they're sets, but what is their purpose?

Comment: @jrd1 actually, no. The code shouldn't be updated, SO isn't a prototyping site. This question should be marked answered, as per your answer, and a new question should be opened with the new problem. This also will help the OP cut his question in smaller problems, which might help him solve it by himself. Imho.

Answer (score 2):

That's not surprising as **you've only read the line *once*** - **you aren't looping over the stream at all**. Your code should be:

```
std::string line
while(std::getline(infile, line)) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;//see what's in the line
    //other code here...
}
```

Why? Because you want to *keep reading from the stream (until an EOF is encountered)*. In other words: **you want to keep reading from the stream *while* you can get a line of data from the stream `infile`**.

UPDATE:

The OP's question is different now relative to the above.

If for example your data file looks like this:

```
123 2978 09809 908098 
198 8796 89791 128797
```

You can read the numbers like this:

```
std::string line
while(std::getline(infile, line)) {
    //you line is populated
    istringstream iss(line);
    int num;

    while (!(iss >> num).fail()) {
        //save the number
    }
    //at this point you've reached the end of one line.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still only reads one line.

while (std::getline(infile, line))
{
    while(iss >> input)
    {        
        set1.insert(input);
    }
}

Comment: @HaakonSjøgren: Correct: because that's how you've done in in your code. Correct me if I am wrong, but your original problem is that you could only read one line. You now have a new unrelated problem - one that's related to other aspects of your code that you didn't address in your original post. Please edit your post to reflect that.

Comment: I don't wish to output the string though, I wish to convert the input-string-stream into ints.

Comment: I edited it once more. Thank you.

Comment: @HaakonSjøgren: I figured as much, and I've edited my question to reflect your update (although, I have no idea what `set1` and `set2` are). However, it should be noted that this is entirely against protocol, as it's only good etiquette to ask a new question if your previous problem was solved.